# Is there a way to reference jQuery inside my master page without having to modify it (same as referencing Alternate CSS URL )

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery, master-page, custom-masterpage, script

I am working on a sharepoint online 2013. and inside my team site collection, i am adding some script editor web parts which uses jQuery. and for sharepoint to understand jQuery code i need to reference the jQuery source file for example `jquery-1.10.2.js`. 
so now i know that i can modify the master page (`seatle.master`) and add i reference to jQuery. but i am not sure if i can add a reference to jQuery without directly modifying the `seatle.master`, in the same way i add a reference to custom css , by going to "site setting>>look and feel>> master page>> set the Alternate CSS URL"?? so is this possible??

Comment: Staple it to the site as a UserCustomAction, https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP/tree/master/Samples/Core.ManageUserCustomAction. I'll give a better answer in the morning.

Comment: @EricAlexander thanks will be waiting for more details. again i am working on sharepoint online 2013.

Comment: Danny covered it, with Alternate CSS and UserCstomActions, there is no need to modify the master page, at all.

Comment: @EricAlexander I agree that using UserCustomActions & Alternate CSS, can minimize the need to modify the master page. unless the modification requested by the customer can not be achieved using alternate css & UserCustomAction. For example if the customer requested to move the site logo to be on the left upper corner of the window, to relocate the search box to be on the right upper corner and to display the current date/time below the user-name. then those kind of modification require to modify the master pages directly and can not be achieved using pure UserCustomactions is this correct ?.

Comment: they aren't real valid reasons to alter the master page in my opinion, i would say no, we aren't going to do that.

Answer (score 3):

You have multiple options:

- load JS files with JSLink assigned to a WebPart, easy to do with the SharePoint UI, but less easy to maintain (and you need a WebPart that can do JSLink on the page)
- set UserCustomAction ScriptLinks, these are functionaly the same as MasterPage ScriptLinks and JSLinks but are stapled on the SiteCollection or only one Web.
  They do **not** require any changes to the MasterPage
  They are also executed on System Pages (where your MasterPage script is not executed)
  **But** you can only set them with code.
  UCAs have been around since SP2010, and the best kept secret
  (note: alas Microsoft decided to remove them from the Modern Experiences (they did work in the first Preview)  They work fine in Classic Mode.

#### Adding UserCustomActions

- Use PNP if you want to add them with Powershell
- Use the [PNP AddIn](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP/tree/master/Samples/Core.ManageUserCustomAction) to install an App in your SiteCollection
- Use [John Liu's ASPX Page UserCustomActions](https://github.com/johnnliu/UserCustomActionsConfigPage), if you want to assign UCAs from within your SiteCollection (it is an ASPX page you have to upload)
  Also great for [learning what UCAs are](https://github.com/johnnliu/UserCustomActionsConfigPage) and peeking at the  [source code](https://github.com/johnnliu/UserCustomActionsConfigPage/blob/master/src/configure-page.js)
- Use the [Chrome Browser Extension SP Editor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-sp-editor/ecblfcmjnbbgaojblcpmjoamegpbodhd/related?hl=en), this doesn't add any App or File to your SiteCollection, also great for accesing the Site property bag (another of those lesser known nuggets)

Comment: ok thanks for your reply. now i agree with you is that referencing jQuery using JSLINK will cause a maintainability problems , when i have many web parts, and i prefer to reference jQuery all over the site collection from one place. second point i did not understand if you are trying to say that using UserCustomActions is not a recommended appraoch as it is considered an old appraoch ?

Comment: third question, is modifying the master page and add the jQuery link to it, is also something i can consider. now i usually do this inside on-premise, but on SP on-line i am trying to prevent customizing the master page , unless the requirements i am trying to implement can not be done without customizing the master page..

Comment: UserCustomActions ScriptLinks are the best way to not change your MasterPage, they have been around since 2010,have always been **and still are** the most powerful way of adding script. (except on Modern Experiences.. **nothing** can be loaded in Modern Experiences

Comment: i have never worked with UsercustomAction, so seems it is the way to go ...

Comment: Hardly anyone knows about them.. even MVPs still stuff stuff in the MasterPage

Comment: so do you mean that most sharepoint developers will modify the master page to reference jQuery and other scripts ? i use to do so inside on-premise SP ,, but for SP online i am trying to avoid this as much as possible..

Comment: Yes, I think 7 out of 10 projects I am called into to clean the mess still changed the MasterPages

Comment: so can i say that you are against modifying the master page , as you mentioned "_..I am called into to clean the mess still changed the MasterPages.._"? and what if the customer asked for some modifications that can not be achieved unless we modify the master page ? can i know your opinion on this ? now as i mentioned i use to modify the master pages on many on-premise projects (of course by taking a copy of the "seatle.master"), and i have never faced any problem, some project have been running for 3 years.Also recently i have installed a refresh sharepoint server 2013 for

Comment: a new customer and i apply the latest CU Nov 2016. at the beginning i though that when i will check the master page for the new site collection i will see many differences comapred to old master pages, but seems that the latest Seattle.master is almost the same as the master page 2-3 years ago. so now many people are against modifying master pages, because they say that a future update can add a new feature to the master pages and since we are are not using the built-in

Comment: seatle.master so we will not benefit from these features.  but seems that the master page seatle.master have not been changed since 3 years . i even copy a master page from a project which i worked on 2 years ago,, inside my new sharepoint 2013 site collection,, and it worked well. so can i know your opinion on this please ?thanks

Comment: My opinion: Do whatever you want with MasterPages; know that Microsoft now advices against them, know that with (more and more) Modern Experience the concept of a MasterPage is gone.

Comment: so if i understand your latest reply correctly, you mean i can custom the master page when i can not do the required customization using user custom actions ? but i need to keep in mind that the master page might break in the future due to some updates or i might lose new features. second question. is your point of view apply to SP online and SP on-premise ? as seems modifying SP online master pages is where more restrictions are being mentioned by MS, while on on-premise seems it is more flexible..??